# Are vectors in the null space of a matrix considered eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From what I've learned about the definition of an eigenvector, it seems like a vector that gets mapped to zero should just be considered an eigenvector where $\lambda = 0$. Is that true, or are those considered a special case?

Comment: In the definition of eigenvector there is nothing special about the scalar$~0$ (in the role of eigenvalue). There is an exception for the _vector_ $\vec0$ (which is considered not an eigenvector for _any_ eigenvalue, although it always satisfies the defining equation). Just reading the definition carefully would make this clear.

Comment: @user8578415 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the exception of the zero vector any vector $v\in\operatorname{null}T$ are eigenvectors of $T$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct by the definition, for $\vec x\neq 0$

$$A\vec x=0\vec x$$

then $\vec x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. Indeed, an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is in the null space of $A-\lambda I$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are eigenvectors (unless it's the null vector).

Comment: Why does the null vector not count? It also fits the definition if you substitute it for x.

Comment: @user8578415 No, it doesn't. By definition, an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a **non-null** vector $v$ such that $A.v=\lambda v$.

Comment: Okay, I see. Why is an exception made for the null vector? I just learned about eigenvectors/values, so I haven't done any problems with them other than example problems, but I would assume that it messes up some kind of application for them, or some other mathy thing that relates to them?

Comment: @user8578415 You can't define an eigenvalue for the zero vector.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.

Comment: For any $A$ and any $\lambda$ the equation $Ax=\lambda x$ is true for $x=0$.. So if we allowed $0$ as an eigenvector then everything would be an eigenvalue of everything, making it a useless concept.

Comment: @user8578415 The concept of an eigenvector answers the question “is there a line (through the origin) that’s mapped to itself by $A$?” You need a non-zero vector to define the direction of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some more perspective -

it is not a special case, Definition itself clarify -

**Any non-zero vector that remains in its own span under a transformation is Eigen vector, i.e. any nonzero vector that changes at most by a scalar factor when that linear transformation is applied to it**

Note that since Zero-vector can be expressed as Linear Combination of any other vector hence its the only vector that can be considered as parallel to any other vector.

therefore, when Transformation matrix A is Singular, that means its Null-space is more than Trivial, and Determinant of A is 0, then we will surely get at least one Eigen-value as 0, and eigen vector correspond to eigen-value 0 is nothing but Null-space of A { except trivial vector }, because any vector in Null-space of A will land on Zero-vector (origin) post transformation . hence technically those vectors will remain in their own span.